# How to share multi-level certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, x509certificate

I recently joined a company and we have been asked by one of our clients to share our certificate so that they can establish a connection with us. We are working on getting an SSO between us. So I pulled up our environment on the browser and when I clicked the certificate, I got a multi-level certificate setup. The certificates are in three levels, the first is Trustwave, second is Trustwave <> Level 1 and the last level is *.<>

I am able to click and open the first two ones, but not the last one. I just have a basic idea on certificates. How do I share this with the client? Do I have to share both the certificates separately or is there a way to combine them and share it as a single file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to this a couple of days back. IE does not allow to export the certificate in the last level, but chrome does. So using chrome, I exported all three certificates to my computer. I exported them in Base-64 encoded format, so when I open them using a text editor, I could see the contents of it. The way to share all three would be to paste the complete contents of the root certificate, followed by the certificate in the next level and so on. So finally I had three certificate entries in one file. Save it as a .pem file and share with the client!